# Curious badge showing 'x' next to positive question record but I have a positive question record

Tags: support

On the main Politics.SE site, when I click on the Curious badge I am seeing an 'x' next to 'need positive question record' but even taking into account deleted questions I have an overwhelmingly positive question record.

The box-out also shows 2/5 days with a well received questions, but I have asked a question with a positive score on at least three days.

Why is the Curious badge info showing these things?

Answer (score 2):

> The box-out also shows 2/5 days with a well received questions, but I have asked a question with a positive score on at least three days.

The criteria is not just having a question with a positive score.  There also needs to be [no negative questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234966/229547) that day.  Negatives include being closed, deleted, and down-voted.

If a question is closed, deleted, *or* down-voted, it is negative.  I do not know whether that means a net negative vote score or any down-vote.  But it certainly means that a question that has a net positive score that is either closed or deleted will block a question from counting as well-received.  Note:  we have an unusually high number of down-votes on this site.  Down-voting is rare on most sites as few questions elsewhere are controversial in and of themselves.

[Original proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/229547) for asking day badges.

Note that they cache badge progress information, so it may well be out of date.  Badges regularly don't get awarded for a period of time after qualification.

Comment: I checked and this isn't the issue. Unless you mean no downvotes at all, which would see a pretty harsh criteria. I have at least 5 positive questions now, on days where I got no downvoted questions. Unless closed questions count as negative even if they are upvoted???

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen  I responded in my answer.